# Issue with date format in input control

Tags: jasperserver

I have a report that takes date range as input control. But when I enter the date in the input control, its format changes automatically and error message is displayed (screenshot attached).

What's going wrong here?

[image: Screenshot_date_issue]

Answer (score 1):

Its because of the date format you have given in the iReport which is `mm/dd/yyyy` and default date format of JasperReport server is `yyyy-MM-dd`.

You can change the date format of JasperReport server which is controlled by the Locale and therefore the locale bundles. 
To change the date format edit `jasperserver_config.properties` which is under

```
\jasperreports-server-cp-5.5.0\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver\WEB-INF\bundles
```

These are the date formats in jasperserver_config.properties file:-

```
date.format=dd-MM-yyyy
datetime.format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm
calendar.date.format=%d-%m-%Y
calendar.datetime.format=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M
```